# R - Sum Values That Match A Pattern/Character in Several Rows Across Several Columns

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, aggregate, multiple-columns

I am looking to sum the values within each of the 'M' columns that have the same character in any of 'Y' columns, so if my data frame looks like this:

```
X     M.1    M.2    M.3    Y.1     Y.2     Y.3
K3    21     6      11     L       N       X   
K8    31     1      29     N                         
K2    8      0      2      L       Q       Z
```

I would like to get this output data frame:

```
Y     M.1    M.2    M.3
L     29     6      13
N     52     7      40
Q      8     0      2
X     21     6      11
```

Bonus if it can include all the values in column X that include the specific character in the 'Y' column into one column, looking like this:

```
Y     M.1    M.2    M.3    X.all
L     29     6      13     K3,K2
N     52     7      40     K3,K8
Q      8     0      2      K2
X     29     6      13     K3
```

So far, using aggregate() function below I can get the sum of each value in the "Y' column individually, but appreciate a better way to make an entirely new data frame with all the sums together

`aggregate(cbind(df$M.1) ~ df$Y.1, data = df, sum)`

Thanks so much for help with this!

Comment: Right now there are blanks under Y.2 and Y.3, which likely get read in as NA. What's the plan for those?

Comment: In the data frame I am working with, there are blanks in several of the Y.2 and Y.3 columns - no plan for them specifically; would you recommend converting the empty values into 'NA'?

Comment: Totally depends on what you need to do with them and whether you want them to have an absence of value, which is basically what `NA` means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `tidyverse` functions, you can do some wrangling in a few steps. I'm breaking it down to see the intermediary results.

About missing values: that's up to you. You didn't `dput` data, so when I read in your data as text with `readr::read_table2`, the blanks are automatically converted to `NA`. Here I'm keeping those missing values.

So first, `tidyr::gather` gets you a long-shaped data frame, first with `Y.1`, etc in a single column:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  gather(key, value = Y, Y.1:Y.3) %>%
  head()
#> # A tibble: 6 x 6
#>   X       M.1   M.2   M.3 key   Y    
#>   <chr> <int> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 K3       21     6    11 Y.1   L    
#> 2 K8       31     1    29 Y.1   N    
#> 3 K2        8     0     2 Y.1   L    
#> 4 K3       21     6    11 Y.2   N    
#> 5 K8       31     1    29 Y.2   <NA> 
#> 6 K2        8     0     2 Y.2   Q
```

A second `gather` puts `Y`s and `M`s into 2 columns:

```r
df %>%
  gather(key, value = Y, Y.1:Y.3) %>%
  gather(key2, value = M, M.1:M.3) %>%
  head()
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>   X     key   Y     key2      M
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>
#> 1 K3    Y.1   L     M.1      21
#> 2 K8    Y.1   N     M.1      31
#> 3 K2    Y.1   L     M.1       8
#> 4 K3    Y.2   N     M.1      21
#> 5 K8    Y.2   <NA>  M.1      31
#> 6 K2    Y.2   Q     M.1       8
```

Then you can group, create a column with the pasted strings such as `K2,K3`, and add up the numeric values. I put `x.all` in the grouping so it wouldn't get dropped after summarizing.

```r
df %>%
  gather(key, value = Y, Y.1:Y.3) %>%
  gather(key2, value = M, M.1:M.3) %>%
  group_by(Y) %>%
  mutate(x.all = sort(X) %>% unique() %>% paste(collapse = ",")) %>%
  group_by(Y, key2, x.all) %>%
  summarise(sum = sum(M, na.rm = T)) %>%
  head()
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Groups:   Y, key2 [6]
#>   Y     key2  x.all   sum
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>
#> 1 L     M.1   K2,K3    29
#> 2 L     M.2   K2,K3     6
#> 3 L     M.3   K2,K3    13
#> 4 N     M.1   K3,K8    52
#> 5 N     M.2   K3,K8     7
#> 6 N     M.3   K3,K8    40
```

Then bring it back into a wide shape with columns for the different `M` variables:

```r
df %>%
  gather(key, value = Y, Y.1:Y.3) %>%
  gather(key2, value = M, M.1:M.3) %>%
  group_by(Y) %>%
  mutate(x.all = sort(X) %>% unique() %>% paste(collapse = ",")) %>%
  group_by(Y, key2, x.all) %>%
  summarise(sum = sum(M, na.rm = T)) %>%
  spread(key = key2, value = sum)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#> # Groups:   Y [6]
#>   Y     x.all   M.1   M.2   M.3
#>   <chr> <chr> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 L     K2,K3    29     6    13
#> 2 N     K3,K8    52     7    40
#> 3 Q     K2        8     0     2
#> 4 X     K3       21     6    11
#> 5 Z     K2        8     0     2
#> 6 <NA>  K8       62     2    58
```

<sup>Created on 2018-10-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

**1) dplyr**

Here is a `dplyr` approach but starting with `reshape` (which has great functionality but the way its arguments work is impossible to remember).

```
library(dplyr)
(df2 <- reshape(df1, varying = c("Y.1", "Y.2", "Y.3"), direction = "long") %>% 
  group_by(Y))
# A tibble: 9 x 7
# Groups:   Y [6]
#  X       M.1   M.2   M.3  time Y        id
#* <chr> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <chr> <int>
#1 K3       21     6    11     1 L         1
#2 K8       31     1    29     1 N         2
#3 K2        8     0     2     1 L         3
#4 K3       21     6    11     2 N         1
#5 K8       31     1    29     2 NA        2
#6 K2        8     0     2     2 Q         3
#7 K3       21     6    11     3 X         1
#8 K8       31     1    29     3 NA        2
#9 K2        8     0     2     3 Z         3
```

Now we can use `left_join` after we summarised `X` and `c("M.1", "M.2", "M.3")` separately.

```
left_join(
  summarise_at(df2, c("M.1", "M.2", "M.3"), .funs = sum),
  mmarise(df2, X = toString(unique(X)))
)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
#  Y       M.1   M.2   M.3 X     
#  <chr> <int> <int> <int> <chr> 
#1 L        29     6    13 K3, K2
#2 N        52     7    40 K8, K3
#3 Q         8     0     2 K2    
#4 X        21     6    11 K3    
#5 Z         8     0     2 K2    
#6 NA       62     2    58 K8
```

---

**2) base R**

Starting from `df2` here is the same idea in `base R` but note that the `NA`s got lost.

```
df2 <- reshape(df1, varying = c("Y.1", "Y.2", "Y.3"), direction = "long")

merge(
  aggregate(cbind(M.1, M.2, M.3) ~ Y, df2, sum),
  aggregate(X ~ Y, df2, toString)
)
#  Y M.1 M.2 M.3      X
#1 L  29   6  13 K3, K2
#2 N  52   7  40 K8, K3
#3 Q   8   0   2     K2
#4 X  21   6  11     K3
#5 Z   8   0   2     K2
```

---

**3) data.table**

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
df2 <- melt(df1, measure.vars = patterns("Y."), value.name = "Y")

# I'm sure there must be a cleverer way than this
df2[df2[, .(X = toString(unique(X))), by = Y], lapply(.SD, sum), .SDcols = c("M.1", "M.2", "M.3"), by = Y, on = "Y"]
```

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(X = c("K3", "K8", "K2"), M.1 = c(21L, 31L, 8L), 
    M.2 = c(6L, 1L, 0L), M.3 = c(11L, 29L, 2L), Y.1 = c("L", 
    "N", "L"), Y.2 = c("N", NA, "Q"), Y.3 = c("X", NA, "Z")), .Names = c("X", 
"M.1", "M.2", "M.3", "Y.1", "Y.2", "Y.3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!